# Изменение InputLanguage в WPF Webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить программно язык ввода для такого контрола как `WebBrowser`. Стандартные методы почему-то не помагают.

Comment: Все работает. Я ошибся в определении `CultureInfo("ru-RU")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Через вин апи:**

Я думаю эта [ссылка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms646305) на мсдн Вам поможет.
А [эта](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/winapi/710692.all.aspx) поможет определиться с параметрами.

Как импортировать из вин апи функции разберётесь?

**Через Шарп**:

Такой код у Вас не работает?

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Только что проверил - работает, в веб браузере переключает раскладку

Comment: Спасибо, действительно все нормально, только я не увидел свой Баг, когда переключался на русский. Там в культуре нужно прописывать *ru-RU* а не просто ru или RU